# Что делать если не срабатывает camera.open()?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, камера, android-camera

Почему у меня не работает камера на 6.0.1 android'е? Пытаюсь сделать фото и сохранить в папку, но завис на этапе снятия фото, не идёт ни как, уже всё перепробовал, может вы поможете.

Манифест :

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Код :

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        try{
            if(clickOn == true) {
                clickOn = false;
                camera = Camera.open(); // ТУТ ВЫЛЕТАЕТ ОШИБКА <=========
                Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
                parameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                camera.setParameters(parameters);
                camera.startPreview();
            } else {
                clickOn = true;
                camera.stopPreview();
                camera.release();
                camera = null;


            }
        }catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", ""+e);
        }
    }
```

Ошибка :

> E/Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service